# Slicing rows df by elements list that begin with a certain str

Tags: pandas

I have a list:

```
['Ad','Cs']
```

And a df

```
       xx  yy  zz
Adjsl   5   7   9
Adjrr   1   1   2
Blsda   6   6   6
Csaosq  8   7   2
```

I would like to know how could I slice the df by only keeping the rows those index beggin with the elements of the list to obtain the following output:

```
       xx  yy  zz
Adjsl   5   7   9
Adjrr   1   1   2
Csaosq  8   7   2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we use [`Series.str.startswith`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html).
Here you can combine it with [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
df_filtered=pd.concat([df[df.index.str.startswith(key)] for key in my_list])
print(df_filtered)

        xx  yy  zz
Adjsl    5   7   9
Adjrr    1   1   2
Csaosq   8   7   2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `match`:

```
lst = ['Ad','Cs']
pattern = '|'.join(lst)

df[df.index.str.match(f'^({pattern})')]
```

output:

```
        xx  yy  zz
Adjsl    5   7   9
Adjrr    1   1   2
Csaosq   8   7   2
```